# How to solve the problem with clone large size file and EOF error occured at git

Tags: git, eof

When I clone large size git repository, EOF Error is occured like below '1. Error Console'.
I tried some kind of method but, all the methods(2. I tried and failed) are failed.
Please Tell me How can I solve this problem...

1. Error Console

   ```
   fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
   fatal: early EOF
   fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
   ```
2. I tried and failed

   1. Increase http.postBuffer

      ```bash
      git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
      ```
   2. partial clone and pull

      ```bash
      git config --global core.compression 0
      git clone --depth 1 [repo_url]
      git fetch --unshallow or git fetch --depth=2147483647
      git pull --all
      ```
   3. modified ~/.gitconfig

      ```bash
      [core] 
      packedGitLimit = 1024m 
      packedGitWindowSize = 1024m 

      [pack] 
      deltaCacheSize = 2047m 
      packSizeLimit = 2047m 
      windowMemory = 2047m
      ```
   4. Using SSH
   5. Using Docker

      ```bash
      docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash  pytorch/pytorch:1.10.0-cuda11.3-cudnn8-runtime
      apt-get update && apt-get install git
      git clone [repo url]
      ```
   6. check Gitlab Host nginx.conf

Comment: Are you going through a proxy?

Comment: yeah I'm using proxy(nginx). I check nginx.conf and check size but some guys can clone and some guys can't.